# can you add metadata to winston custom transport?

Tags: node.js, winston

I am writing a custom transport for winston, and I have it working, but now I would like to pass metadata to the custom transport. Is there any way of doing this? I don't see it being passed into the `log` function that I have implemented for my custom transport.